# Three div's one always on center

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to write my new webpage. On the top I want to have one center div called top-bar-container, with three other `div`'s something like that :

```
<div id="top-bar-container">
    <div id="top-main-menu-container">
        <ul id="main-menu">
            <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="logo-placeholder">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" width="300" height="75"></a>
    </div>

    <div id="mail-login-container">

    </div>
</div>
```

When trying to get the effect of a `div` to the left was always on the extreme left, right, to the right and the logo was always in the middle. I like to use position: absolute but this reluctance. I have to deal differently. Is anyone able to help me get this effect?

Comment: css has [float](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) which may help you. Otherwise you may also use a [table](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)

Comment: If you ant to lear html & css find some basic tutorials (there are a lot of nice and fun stuff on the web w8 for you).  For this basically you have to set width (or max-width) of container to make boundaries and center it with margin auto or text-align center

Comment: Never use tables for that (NEVER! ever if it not 1990's ).  Floats can be use only in specific situations (if it not 2000's).  Now in half of 2010's we use GRID! We don't live in Dark Ages. For you the best thing to do will be lear how to use grid, http://j4n.co/blog/Creating-your-own-css-grid-system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it.

```
#top-bar-container > div {
 float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can float the links left, then float the mail container right.  Apply a text-align center to the parent div and everything should be fine.

```
#top-bar-container {
    text-align: center;
}
#top-main-menu-container {
    float:left;
}
#mail-login-container {
    float:right;
}
```

Fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/3eut86s6/